# ignorar linhas existentes no banco, na importação de arquivo php

Tags: php, arquivo, sql-insert

Tenho a seguinte linha de código que realiza a importação de arquivo txt.

```
<?php
    function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
      $sts = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados(loja, cod_prod, cod_acesso, desc_prod, estoq_disp, data, estoq_validade) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
      $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(2, $itens[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(3, $itens[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(4, $itens[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(5, $itens[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(6, $itens[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->bindValue(7, $itens[6], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sts->execute();
      $sts->closeCursor();
      $sts = NULL;
}
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
    $Pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vencimento", "root", "");
    $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while (!feof($file)){
        $linha = fgets($file);          
        $itens = explode(';', $linha);          
        Inserir($itens, $Pdo);
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arquivo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Preciso que na hora de inserir no banco de dados as linhas do arquivo que forem exatamente iguais as já existentes dentro do banco de dados ele ignore aquela linha e insira somente as que não são iguais.

Comment: Ante de chamar a função `Inserir()`, você precisa checar se aquela linha atual não já existe no banco, se existir, não faz nada, se não existir, chama a função `Inserir()`.

Comment: @LeandroLima eu entendi, só não sei como que faria para colocar essa função dentro desse código, você consegue me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código verificando se essa linha já está cadastrada no banco de dados:

```
function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
  $sts = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados(loja, cod_prod, cod_acesso, desc_prod, estoq_disp, data, estoq_validade) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
  $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(2, $itens[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(3, $itens[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(4, $itens[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(5, $itens[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(6, $itens[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->bindValue(7, $itens[6], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sts->execute();
  $sts->closeCursor();
  $sts = NULL;
}
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
    $pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vencimento", "root", "");
    $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while (!feof($file)){
        $linha = fgets($file);          
        $itens = explode(';', $linha); 

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM dados
                                        WHERE loja = '{$itens[0]}' and
                                        cod_prod = '{$itens[1]}' and
                                        cod_acesso = '{$itens[2]}' and
                                        desc_prod = '{$itens[3]}' and
                                        estoq_disp = '{$itens[4]}' and
                                        data = '{$itens[5]}' and
                                        estoq_validade = '{$itens[6]}';";

        $check = $pdo->query($query);

        $result = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Verificase o valor retornado é 0 (Nenhum dado igual cadastrado)
        if($result['total'] == 0){
            Inserir($itens, $pdo);
        }else{
            //Vai cair aqui caso ja exista essa linha cadastrada
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentei realizar conforme passou mas dá erro na execução.

Comment: Qual o erro que aconteceu?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in no arquivo importar.php na linha 24.

minha linha 24 do aquivo é:
    $check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM dados

Comment: Pronto, o código está OK agora, tinha alguns erros com a diferença dos nomes da variável `$Pdo` e `$pdo`, e também alguns erros na query, eu tinha feito sem testar, mas agora está funcionando. Se aparecer mais algum erro coloca aqui.